# Erro Na Validação do ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou querendo retornar os erros de validação dos meus model. Só que recebo uma mensagem de erro quando tento cadastrar.

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Web.Mvc.ModelErrorCollection]

Estou colocando a validação no *controller*:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ClienteViewModel viewmodel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Set<Pessoa>().Add(viewmodel.Pessoa);

            if (viewmodel.Cliente.TipoPessoa.Equals(Models.Enum.TipoPessoa.Juridica))
            {
                db.Set<PessoaJuridica>().Add(viewmodel.PessoaJuridica);
            }
            else {
                db.Set<PessoaFisica>().Add(viewmodel.PessoaFisica);
            }

            db.Cliente.Add(viewmodel.Cliente);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else {
            string erros = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count() > 0).ToString();
            ModelState.AddModelError("", erros);

        }

       // ViewBag.PessoaId = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaId", "Nome", cliente.PessoaId);
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

Na *ViewModel* apenas estancio as classes `Pessoa`, `PessoaJuridica` e `Fisica`.

**EDIT**

O erro acontece nessa linha onde retorno para view.

```
string erros = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count() > 0).ToString();
            ModelState.AddModelError("", erros);
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o erro completo? Ele acontece em tempo de execução?

Comment: Em qual linha este erro é gerado? No `if (ModelState.IsValid)` ?

Comment: Acrescentei a linha, o erro é armazenado dentro da variável erros.

Answer (score 2):

Isso aqui está errado, você não pode fazer desta forma:

```
string erros = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count() > 0).ToString();
```

Você está transformando uma coleção em string e quando você faz isso a string que é retornada é essa

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Web.Mvc.ModelErrorCollection]

**Solução**

O correto é você transformar os itens da coleção em string, uma possível solução seria:

Considerando que `x.Value.Errors` é uma coleção

```
string erros =string.Join(", ",ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count() > 0).SelectAll(z => z.ToArray() ));
```

Assim você junta todos os itens da coleção e os transforma em string separado por virgula.

Comment: Ceerto, mas desse modo recebo esse erro: `System.Web.Mvc.ModelErrorCollection`

Comment: `x.Value.Errors` esse Errors é uma coleção?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração considerando que `x.Value.Errors` é uma coleção

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei por `foreach` e funcionou dessa forma:

```
var ListaErros = new List<string>();
                foreach (var values in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var erros in values.Errors)
                    {
                        ListaErros.Add(erros.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

Pegue a lista de erros

```
var ListErro = ModelState.Where(a => a.Value.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid).Select(a => a.Key + " " + a.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage).ToList()
```